# Build failing after upgrading to Angular 6

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

I just upgraded my Angular 5 project to 6. And build is failing with:

> ERROR in node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker-service.d.ts(5,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/myapp/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead.d.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/myapp/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

**NOTE:**

This problem occurs if adding `ng-bootstrap` to the project (even a new Angular 6 project).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do this:

```
npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save
```

Comment: This answer, combined with the [official update guide](https://update.angular.io/) did the trick for me for a similar problem.

Comment: yup, you were missing rxjs-compat. Even though the docs say that ng upgrade will add it, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use v2.0.0 of `ng-bootstrap` which is now compatible with Angular 6. Update dependency in `package.json`:

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0"
```

This way you don't need `rxjs-compat`, but make sure your code is RxJs 6 compatible. Also note the breaking changes of ng-bootstrap [2.0.0](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-2018-05-04) release.

Comment: Even 3.x.x is better. This one is for angular 6.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to update RxJS with `RxJS 6.0.0` as per changelog

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#dependency-updates
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md
- https://update.angular.io/

Comment: After the update I had rxjs 6.1.0 and typescript 2.7.2 but tslib was missing. I added tslib 1.9.0 to "dependencies" but the build still fails with the same error.

Comment: see the updated link about Rxjs in answer may help you

Comment: I did that too before the first build and I still get the same errors everytime. This is a clean project with just one component.

Comment: Because `In Angular CLI v6 it is by design that arguments only work with the double dash. The correct argument is only --prod, and -prod will not work.`